# is it possible to write a restful web service to accept http request object

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I am new to web service writing using jersey and having requirement to write a web service that will accept http request object, so is it possible to write a restful web service that will accept the http request using the jersey.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by object?

Comment: HttpServletRequest object...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to inject the request object into the jersey service endpoint

```
 @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Ref: [LINK](http://kahwah.me/2011/1/setting-rest-service-jersey-0)